# How can i convert array([array([]) to 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I load a feather file throught python 3.7 that contains arrays inside an array, example:

```
print(X)

array([array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])])
```

and i'm trying to convert `X` to:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

How can i do that?

Thank You.

Comment: Numpy already do that. At least the last version (1.20). Indeed, `np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])]).shape` is `(2,2)`

Comment: Otherwise this could help https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html?highlight=asarray#numpy.asarray
`x = np.asarray(x)`

Comment: @JérômeRichard, you made this array from a list of arrays.  The OP has an object dtype array, which is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.stack`:

```
import numpy as np
np.stack(X)
```